# How to make custom dotted circular progressbar in android?

Tags: android

I have searched for the **dotted circular progress bar** but i din get any perfect examples , There are circular progressbar but not with the **dotted** one So I have implemented hoping that it will help someone, and you can keep this as reference and customize further, for beginners it will help a lot to understand the code as its commented on each line what it is doing.

Comment: pls leave a comment if u downvote this..so that i can understand why you are downvoting. We don post answer simply without searching, I have struggled to search this so i dont want other guys to experience the same.

Answer (score 14):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.naveenbm.customcircleprogressbar.MainActivity"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.example.custom.customcircleprogressbar.CricleProgressBarCustom
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></com.example.custom.customcircleprogressbar.CricleProgressBarCustom>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CircleProgressBarCustom.java**

```
public class CricleProgressBarCustom extends View {

//Normal dot radius
private int dotRadius = 10;

//Expanded Dot Radius
private int bounceDotRadius = 13;

//to get identified in which position dot has to expand its radius
private int dotPosition = 1;

//specify how many dots you need in a progressbar
private int dotAmount = 10;

//specify the circle radius
private int circleRadius = 50;


public CricleProgressBarCustom(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CricleProgressBarCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CricleProgressBarCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    //Animation called when attaching to the window, i.e to your screen
    startAnimation();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //take the point to the center of the screen
    canvas.translate(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2);

    Paint progressPaint = new Paint();
    progressPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff014e"));

    //call create dot method
    createDotInCircle(canvas,progressPaint);
}

private void createDotInCircle(Canvas canvas,Paint progressPaint) {
    //angle for each dot angle = (360/number of dots) i.e  (360/10)
    int angle = 36;

    for(int i = 1; i <= dotAmount; i++){

        if(i == dotPosition){
             // angle should be in radians  i.e formula (angle *(Math.PI / 180))
            float x = (float) (circleRadius * (Math.cos((angle * i) * (Math.PI / 180))));
            float y = (float) (circleRadius * (Math.sin((angle * i) * (Math.PI / 180))));

            canvas.drawCircle(x,y, bounceDotRadius, progressPaint);

        }else{
            // angle should be in radians  i.e formula (angle *(Math.PI / 180))
            float x = (float) (circleRadius * (Math.cos((angle * i) * (Math.PI / 180))));
            float y = (float) (circleRadius * (Math.sin((angle * i) * (Math.PI / 180))));

            canvas.drawCircle(x,y, dotRadius, progressPaint);

        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    //Dynamically setting width and height to progressbar 100 is circle radius, dotRadius * 3 to cover the width and height of Progressbar
     width = 100 + (dotRadius*3);
     height = 100 + (dotRadius*3);

    //MUST CALL THIS
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void startAnimation() {
    BounceAnimation bounceAnimation = new BounceAnimation();
    bounceAnimation.setDuration(150);
    bounceAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    bounceAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    bounceAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            dotPosition++;
            //when dotPosition == dotAmount , then start again applying animation from 0th positon , i.e  dotPosition = 0;
            if (dotPosition > dotAmount) {
                dotPosition = 1;
            }


        }
    });
    startAnimation(bounceAnimation);
}


private class BounceAnimation extends Animation {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        //call invalidate to redraw your view againg.
        invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

**Snap Shot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One example I can suggest you for this various Progress Bar with Smooth Working

https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit

You put the class..

if You want Circle progress bar than Work it Like..

Take a TextView Where You Want...

And First Take..On your Class where You Use.(Declaration)

```
   private Circle mCircleDrawable = new Circle();
```

Than in your Oncreate take this..

```
    mCircleDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    mCircleDrawable.setColor(R.color.colorPrimary);// What u want of color progress bar dots...

TextView progressBar_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress);// Your Textview..
    progressBar_text.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, mCircleDrawable, null);// Set Progress bar on Textview..
```

You Need to Start the

```
    mCircleDrawable.start();
```

You also Stop the Circle when You exit. On Detroyed Or on PostMethod..If use(AYSNC)

```
mCircleDrawable.stop();
```

The Classes Used For this...

You can Use all the Library for this and take any progress bar you need using Upper Link Example

Circle.java

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;

import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.animation.SpriteAnimatorBuilder;
import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.sprite.CircleSprite;
import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.sprite.CircleSpriteGroup;
import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.sprite.Sprite;


 public class Circle extends CircleSpriteGroup {

@Override
public Sprite[] onCreateChild() {
    Dot[] dots = new Dot[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new Dot();
        dots[i].setAnimationDelay(1200 / 12 * i + -1200);
    }
    return dots;
}

class Dot extends CircleSprite {

    public Dot() {
        setScale(0f);
    }

    @Override
    public ValueAnimator getAnimation() {
        float fractions[] = new float[]{0f, 0.5f, 1f};
        return new SpriteAnimatorBuilder(this).
                scale(fractions, 0f, 1f, 0f).
                duration(1200).
                easeInOut(fractions)
                .build();
    }
}
}
```

SpriteAnimatorBuilder.Java

```
import android.animation.Keyframe;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder;
import android.util.Property;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;


import    com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.animation.interpolator.KeyFrameInterpolator;
import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.sprite.Sprite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class SpriteAnimatorBuilder {
private Sprite sprite;
private List<PropertyValuesHolder> propertyValuesHolders = new ArrayList<>  ();
private Interpolator interpolator;
private int repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE;
private long duration = 2000;

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder(Sprite sprite) {
    this.sprite = sprite;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder scale(float fractions[], float... scale) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.SCALE, scale);
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder alpha(float fractions[], int... alpha) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.ALPHA, alpha);
    return this;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public SpriteAnimatorBuilder scaleX(float fractions[], float... scaleX) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.SCALE, scaleX);
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder scaleY(float fractions[], float... scaleY) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.SCALE_Y, scaleY);
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder rotateX(float fractions[], int... rotateX) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.ROTATE_X, rotateX);
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder rotateY(float fractions[], int... rotateY) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.ROTATE_Y, rotateY);
    return this;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public SpriteAnimatorBuilder translateX(float fractions[], int... translateX) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.TRANSLATE_X, translateX);
    return this;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public SpriteAnimatorBuilder translateY(float fractions[], int... translateY) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.TRANSLATE_Y, translateY);
    return this;
}


public SpriteAnimatorBuilder rotate(float fractions[], int... rotate) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.ROTATE, rotate);
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder translateXPercentage(float fractions[], float... translateXPercentage) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.TRANSLATE_X_PERCENTAGE, translateXPercentage);
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder translateYPercentage(float[] fractions, float... translateYPercentage) {
    holder(fractions, Sprite.TRANSLATE_Y_PERCENTAGE, translateYPercentage);
    return this;
}

public PropertyValuesHolder holder(float[] fractions, Property property, float[] values) {
    ensurePair(fractions.length, values.length);
    Keyframe[] keyframes = new Keyframe[fractions.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        keyframes[i] = Keyframe.ofFloat(fractions[i], values[i]);
    }
    PropertyValuesHolder valuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.
            ofKeyframe(property
                    , keyframes
            );
    propertyValuesHolders.add(valuesHolder);
    return valuesHolder;
}

public PropertyValuesHolder holder(float[] fractions, Property property, int[] values) {
    ensurePair(fractions.length, values.length);
    Keyframe[] keyframes = new Keyframe[fractions.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        keyframes[i] = Keyframe.ofInt(fractions[i], values[i]);
    }
    PropertyValuesHolder valuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.
            ofKeyframe(property
                    , keyframes
            );
    propertyValuesHolders.add(valuesHolder);
    return valuesHolder;
}

private void ensurePair(int fractionsLength, int valuesLength) {
    if (fractionsLength != valuesLength) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                Locale.getDefault(),
                "The fractions.length must equal values.length, " +
                        "fraction.length[%d], values.length[%d]",
                fractionsLength,
                valuesLength));
    }
}


public SpriteAnimatorBuilder interpolator(Interpolator interpolator) {
    this.interpolator = interpolator;
    return this;
}

public SpriteAnimatorBuilder easeInOut(float... fractions) {
    interpolator(KeyFrameInterpolator.easeInOut(
            fractions
    ));
    return this;
}


public SpriteAnimatorBuilder duration(long duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
    return this;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public SpriteAnimatorBuilder repeatCount(int repeatCount) {
    this.repeatCount = repeatCount;
    return this;
}


public ObjectAnimator build() {
    PropertyValuesHolder[] holders = new PropertyValuesHolder[propertyValuesHolders.size()];
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(sprite,
            propertyValuesHolders.toArray(holders));
    animator.setDuration(duration);
    animator.setRepeatCount(repeatCount);
    animator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    return animator;
}

}
```

CircleSprite.java

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;


public class CircleSprite extends ShapeSprite {

@Override
public ValueAnimator getAnimation() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void drawShape(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    if (getDrawBounds() != null) {
        int radius = Math.min(getDrawBounds().width(), getDrawBounds().height()) / 2;
        canvas.drawCircle(getDrawBounds().centerX(),
                getDrawBounds().centerY(),
                radius, paint);
    }
}
}
```

ShapeSprite .java

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;


 public abstract class ShapeSprite extends Sprite {

 private Paint mPaint;
 private int mUseColor;
private int mBaseColor;

 public ShapeSprite() {
     setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(mUseColor);
}

@Override
public void setColor(int color) {
    mBaseColor = color;
    updateUseColor();
}

@Override
public int getColor() {
    return mBaseColor;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public int getUseColor() {
    return mUseColor;
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    super.setAlpha(alpha);
    updateUseColor();
}

private void updateUseColor() {
    int alpha = getAlpha();
    alpha += alpha >> 7;
    final int baseAlpha = mBaseColor >>> 24;
    final int useAlpha = baseAlpha * alpha >> 8;
    mUseColor = (mBaseColor << 8 >>> 8) | (useAlpha << 24);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    mPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
}

@Override
protected final void drawSelf(Canvas canvas) {
    mPaint.setColor(mUseColor);
    drawShape(canvas, mPaint);
}

public abstract void drawShape(Canvas canvas, Paint paint);
```

}

CircleSpriteGroup .java

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;


 public abstract class CircleSpriteGroup extends SpriteGroup {

@Override
public void drawChild(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        Sprite sprite = getChildAt(i);
        int count = canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(i * 360 / getChildCount(),
                getBounds().centerX(),
                getBounds().centerY());
        sprite.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    bounds = clipSquare(bounds);
    int radius = (int) (bounds.width() * Math.PI / 3.6f / getChildCount());
    int left = bounds.centerX() - radius;
    int right = bounds.centerX() + radius;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        Sprite sprite = getChildAt(i);
        sprite.setDrawBounds(left, bounds.top, right, bounds.top + radius * 2);
    }
}
  }
```

Sprite.java

```
 import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
 import android.graphics.Camera;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
 import android.graphics.Matrix;
 import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Animatable;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.util.Property;

 import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.animation.AnimationUtils;
 import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.animation.FloatProperty;
 import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.animation.IntProperty;


public abstract class Sprite extends Drawable implements
    ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener
    , Animatable
    , Drawable.Callback {

private float scale = 1;
private float scaleX = 1;
private float scaleY = 1;
private float pivotX;
private float pivotY;
private int animationDelay;
private int rotateX;
private int rotateY;
private int translateX;
private int translateY;
private int rotate;
private float translateXPercentage;
private float translateYPercentage;
private ValueAnimator animator;
private int alpha = 255;
private static final Rect ZERO_BOUNDS_RECT = new Rect();
protected Rect drawBounds = ZERO_BOUNDS_RECT;
private Camera mCamera;
private Matrix mMatrix;

public Sprite() {
    mCamera = new Camera();
    mMatrix = new Matrix();
}

public abstract int getColor();

public abstract void setColor(int color);

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
}

@Override
public int getAlpha() {
    return alpha;
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
}

public float getTranslateXPercentage() {
    return translateXPercentage;
}

public void setTranslateXPercentage(float translateXPercentage) {
    this.translateXPercentage = translateXPercentage;
}

public float getTranslateYPercentage() {
    return translateYPercentage;
}

public void setTranslateYPercentage(float translateYPercentage) {
    this.translateYPercentage = translateYPercentage;
}

public int getTranslateX() {
    return translateX;
}

public void setTranslateX(int translateX) {
    this.translateX = translateX;
}

public int getTranslateY() {
    return translateY;
}

public void setTranslateY(int translateY) {
    this.translateY = translateY;
}

public int getRotate() {
    return rotate;
}

public void setRotate(int rotate) {
    this.rotate = rotate;
}

public float getScale() {
    return scale;
}

public void setScale(float scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
    setScaleX(scale);
    setScaleY(scale);
}

public float getScaleX() {
    return scaleX;
}

public void setScaleX(float scaleX) {
    this.scaleX = scaleX;
}

public float getScaleY() {
    return scaleY;
}

public void setScaleY(float scaleY) {
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
}

public int getRotateX() {
    return rotateX;
}

public void setRotateX(int rotateX) {
    this.rotateX = rotateX;
}

public int getRotateY() {
    return rotateY;
}

public void setRotateY(int rotateY) {
    this.rotateY = rotateY;
}

public float getPivotX() {
    return pivotX;
}

public void setPivotX(float pivotX) {
    this.pivotX = pivotX;
}

public float getPivotY() {
    return pivotY;
}

public void setPivotY(float pivotY) {
    this.pivotY = pivotY;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public int getAnimationDelay() {
    return animationDelay;
}

public Sprite setAnimationDelay(int animationDelay) {
    this.animationDelay = animationDelay;
    return this;
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

}

public abstract ValueAnimator getAnimation();

@Override
public void start() {
    if (AnimationUtils.isStarted(animator)) {
        return;
    }

    animator = obtainAnimation();
    if (animator == null) {
        return;
    }

    AnimationUtils.start(animator);
    invalidateSelf();
}

public ValueAnimator obtainAnimation() {
    if (animator == null) {
        animator = getAnimation();
    }
    if (animator != null) {
        animator.addUpdateListener(this);
        animator.setStartDelay(animationDelay);
    }
    return animator;
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    if (AnimationUtils.isStarted(animator)) {
        animator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        animator.end();
        reset();
    }
}

protected abstract void drawSelf(Canvas canvas);

public void reset() {
    scale = 1;
    rotateX = 0;
    rotateY = 0;
    translateX = 0;
    translateY = 0;
    rotate = 0;
    translateXPercentage = 0f;
    translateYPercentage = 0f;
}

@Override
public boolean isRunning() {
    return AnimationUtils.isRunning(animator);
}

@Override
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    setDrawBounds(bounds);
}

public void setDrawBounds(Rect drawBounds) {
    setDrawBounds(drawBounds.left, drawBounds.top, drawBounds.right, drawBounds.bottom);
}

public void setDrawBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    this.drawBounds = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    setPivotX(getDrawBounds().centerX());
    setPivotY(getDrawBounds().centerY());
}

@Override
public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
    invalidateSelf();
}

@Override
public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {

}

@Override
public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    final Callback callback = getCallback();
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.invalidateDrawable(this);
    }
}

public Rect getDrawBounds() {
    return drawBounds;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    int tx = getTranslateX();
    tx = tx == 0 ? (int) (getBounds().width() * getTranslateXPercentage()) : tx;
    int ty = getTranslateY();
    ty = ty == 0 ? (int) (getBounds().height() * getTranslateYPercentage()) : ty;
    canvas.translate(tx, ty);
    canvas.scale(getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getPivotX(), getPivotY());
    canvas.rotate(getRotate(), getPivotX(), getPivotY());

    if (getRotateX() != 0 || getRotateY() != 0) {
        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.rotateX(getRotateX());
        mCamera.rotateY(getRotateY());
        mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
        mMatrix.preTranslate(-getPivotX(), -getPivotY());
        mMatrix.postTranslate(getPivotX(), getPivotY());
        mCamera.restore();
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
    }
    drawSelf(canvas);
}

public Rect clipSquare(Rect rect) {
    int w = rect.width();
    int h = rect.height();
    int min = Math.min(w, h);
    int cx = rect.centerX();
    int cy = rect.centerY();
    int r = min / 2;
    return new Rect(
            cx - r,
            cy - r,
            cx + r,
            cy + r
    );
}

public static final Property<Sprite, Integer> ROTATE_X = new IntProperty<Sprite>("rotateX") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, int value) {
        object.setRotateX(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getRotateX();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Integer> ROTATE = new IntProperty<Sprite>("rotate") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, int value) {
        object.setRotate(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getRotate();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Integer> ROTATE_Y = new IntProperty<Sprite>("rotateY") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, int value) {
        object.setRotateY(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getRotateY();
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Property<Sprite, Integer> TRANSLATE_X = new IntProperty<Sprite>("translateX") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, int value) {
        object.setTranslateX(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getTranslateX();
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Property<Sprite, Integer> TRANSLATE_Y = new IntProperty<Sprite>("translateY") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, int value) {
        object.setTranslateY(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getTranslateY();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Float> TRANSLATE_X_PERCENTAGE = new FloatProperty<Sprite>("translateXPercentage") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, float value) {
        object.setTranslateXPercentage(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getTranslateXPercentage();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Float> TRANSLATE_Y_PERCENTAGE = new FloatProperty<Sprite>("translateYPercentage") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, float value) {
        object.setTranslateYPercentage(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getTranslateYPercentage();
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Property<Sprite, Float> SCALE_X = new FloatProperty<Sprite>("scaleX") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, float value) {
        object.setScaleX(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getScaleX();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Float> SCALE_Y = new FloatProperty<Sprite>("scaleY") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, float value) {
        object.setScaleY(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getScaleY();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Float> SCALE = new FloatProperty<Sprite>("scale") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, float value) {
        object.setScale(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getScale();
    }
};

public static final Property<Sprite, Integer> ALPHA = new IntProperty<Sprite>("alpha") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Sprite object, int value) {
        object.setAlpha(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Sprite object) {
        return object.getAlpha();
    }
};

   }
```

KeyFrameInterpolator.java

```
 import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;
 import android.view.animation.Interpolator;


 public class KeyFrameInterpolator implements Interpolator {

private TimeInterpolator interpolator;
private float[] fractions;


public static KeyFrameInterpolator easeInOut(float... fractions) {
    KeyFrameInterpolator interpolator = new KeyFrameInterpolator(Ease.inOut());
    interpolator.setFractions(fractions);
    return interpolator;
}

public KeyFrameInterpolator(TimeInterpolator interpolator) {
    this.interpolator = interpolator;
}

public void setFractions(float... fractions) {
    this.fractions = fractions;
}

@Override
public synchronized float getInterpolation(float input) {
    if (fractions.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fractions.length - 1; i++) {
            float start = fractions[i];
            float end = fractions[i + 1];
            float duration = end - start;
            if (input >= start && input <= end) {
                input = (input - start) / duration;
                return start + (interpolator.getInterpolation(input)
                        * duration);
            }
        }
    }
    return interpolator.getInterpolation(input);
}
 }
```

AnimationUtils.java

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;

import com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.sprite.Sprite;

public class AnimationUtils {

public static void start(Animator animator) {
    if (animator != null && !animator.isStarted()) {
        animator.start();
    }
}

public static void stop(Animator animator) {
    if (animator != null && !animator.isRunning()) {
        animator.end();
    }
}

public static void start(Sprite... sprites) {
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.start();
    }
}

public static void stop(Sprite... sprites) {
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.stop();
    }
}

public static boolean isRunning(Sprite... sprites) {
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        if (sprite.isRunning()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isRunning(ValueAnimator animator) {
    return animator != null && animator.isRunning();
}

public static boolean isStarted(ValueAnimator animator) {
    return animator != null && animator.isStarted();
}
}
```

FloatProperty.java

```
 import android.util.Property;


 public abstract class FloatProperty<T> extends Property<T, Float> {

public FloatProperty(String name) {
    super(Float.class, name);
}

/**
 * A type-specific override of the {@link #set(Object, Float)} that is faster when dealing
 * with fields of type <code>float</code>.
 */
public abstract void setValue(T object, float value);

@Override
final public void set(T object, Float value) {
    setValue(object, value);
}

   }
```

IntProperty.java

```
 import android.util.Property;


 public abstract class IntProperty<T> extends Property<T, Integer> {

 public IntProperty(String name) {
    super(Integer.class, name);
}


 public abstract void setValue(T object, int value);

@Override
final public void set(T object, Integer value) {
    setValue(object, value);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin way of the **[great answer from @Naveen Shriyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37807632/7756799)**:

```
class CustomDottedProgressBar : View {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

//Normal dot radius
private val dotRadius = 10F

//Expanded Dot Radius
private val bounceDotRadius = 15F

//to get identified in which position dot has to expand its radius
private var dotPosition = 0

//specify the circle radius
private val circleRadius = 50

// specify the sizes of dots
private val dotRadiusList = arrayListOf(2F, 3F, 4F, 5F, 6F, 7F, 8F, 9F, 10F)

//specify how many dots you need in a progressbar
private val dotAmount = dotRadiusList.size

private val progressPaint = Paint()

override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    //Animation called when attaching to the window, i.e to your screen
    startAnimation()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    //take the point to the center of the screen
    canvas.translate((this.width / 2).toFloat(), (this.height / 2).toFloat())
    progressPaint.color = context.getColor(R.color.orange)

    //call create dot method
    createDotInCircle(canvas, progressPaint)
}

private fun createDotInCircle(canvas: Canvas, progressPaint: Paint) {
    //angle for each dot angle = (360/number of dots) i.e  (360/10)
    val angle = 360 / dotAmount
    for (i in 0 until dotAmount) {
        if (i == dotPosition) {
            // angle should be in radians  i.e formula (angle *(Math.PI / 180))
            val x = (circleRadius * cos(angle * i * (Math.PI / 180))).toFloat()
            val y = (circleRadius * sin(angle * i * (Math.PI / 180))).toFloat()
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, bounceDotRadius, progressPaint)
        } else {
            // angle should be in radians  i.e formula (angle *(Math.PI / 180))
            val x = (circleRadius * cos(angle * i * (Math.PI / 180))).toFloat()
            val y = (circleRadius * sin(angle * i * (Math.PI / 180))).toFloat()
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, dotRadiusList[i], progressPaint)
        }
    }
}

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

    //Dynamically setting width and height to progressbar 100 is circle radius, dotRadius * 3 to cover the width and height of Progressbar
    val width = 100 + dotRadius * 3
    val height = 100 + dotRadius * 3

    //MUST CALL THIS
    setMeasuredDimension(width.roundToInt(), height.roundToInt())
}

private fun startAnimation() {
    val bounceAnimation = BounceAnimation()
    bounceAnimation.duration = 75
    bounceAnimation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    bounceAnimation.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    bounceAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {}
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {
            dotPosition++
            //when dotPosition == dotAmount , then start again applying animation from 0th position , i.e  dotPosition = 0;
            if (dotPosition > dotAmount) {
                dotPosition = 0
            }
        }
    })
    startAnimation(bounceAnimation)
}

private inner class BounceAnimation : Animation() {
    override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t)
        //call invalidate to redraw your view again.
        invalidate()
    }
}}
```